# The right way to call http for every route AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I really new with **AngularJs** and I'm trying to create multiple routes with different `$http` requests. My problem start when the route change and the page content show later.
I figure it out in some way and i think its not the right way.
Hope someone can tell me if there is a better way.

**Note:** AngularJs version: 1.6 | Using ui router

**main.js**

```
var asTwl = angular.module('asTwl', ['ui.router']);

asTwl.controller('generals', function($scope, $http, $timeout){

    $scope.pageLoader = false;

    $scope.getPageData = function(path, postData, obj){
        $scope.pageLoader = true; 
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: path,
            data: postData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data) {
                $scope.data[obj] = JSON.parse(response.data);
                $timeout(function(){
                    $scope.pageLoader = false;
                }, 100)
             }
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            new Error('Error: ', e);
            throw e;
        })
    }
});

asTwl.controller('homePage', function($scope, $http){   
    var postData = {
      //data...
    }
    $scope.getPageData('path', postData, 'home')
})

asTwl.controller('singlePage', function($scope, $http, $stateParams){   
    var postData = $stateParams;
    $scope.getPageData('path', postData, 'page')
})

asTwl.controller('categoryPage', function($scope, $http, $stateParams){   
    var postData = $stateParams;
    $scope.getPageData('path', postData, 'category')
})

asTwl.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl : 'templates/pages/home.html',
        controller : 'homePage'
    })
    .state('info', {
        url: '/info/:id',
        templateUrl : 'templates/pages/info.html',
        controller : 'singlePage'
    })
    .state('category', {
        url: '/category/:type/:id',
        templateUrl : 'templates/pages/category.html',
        controller : 'categoryPage'
    })
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Angular version? Also this looks like UI router. if so please specify it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create a service which will be responsible for communicating with Server/API for playing around with data. You could include that method `getPageData` in that, it returns a promise object.

**Service**

```
app.service('myService', function($http){
   var self = this;
   self.getPageData = function(path, postData){
        return $http.post(path,postData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        .catch(function(e) {
            new Error('Error: ', e);
            throw e;
    });
});
```

Then you could easily utilize the `resolve` option of state of `ui-router` will wait till your ajax promise gets resolved.

```
.state('info', {
    url: '/info/:id',
    templateUrl : 'templates/pages/info.html',
    controller : 'singlePage',
    resolve: {
       getData: function(myService) {
          return myService.getPageData('path', {}, 'info')
       }
    }
})
```

Comment: OP using `$stateParameters`, which can be passed to resolve function via angular DI

Answer (score 4):

First, wrap your `$http` calls to services.  Next,try to use `resolve` https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

**Edit**

Ok, example is here (without wrapping to service):

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl : 'templates/pages/home.html',
    controller : 'homePage',
    resolve: {
       routeData:  function($http){
        return $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'path',
        data: postData /* your POST data - i don't know what is it for your code*/,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'               }
        })
     }
    }
})
.state('info', {
    url: '/info/:id',
    templateUrl : 'templates/pages/info.html',
    controller : 'singlePage'
})
.state('category', {
    url: '/category/:type/:id',
    templateUrl : 'templates/pages/category.html',
    controller : 'categoryPage'
})
```

And in controller:

```
asTwl.controller('homePage', function($scope, routeData){   
      $scope.someData = routeData;
})
```

Comment: You can show me a specific example? something with my code?...i tried use resolve but its became very difficult when i added more route states.

Comment: I upvoied this because this is the correct way to go, you can and should abstract http call to an angular service/services and then resolve function would be simpler, also you can have many "state router" files. so no need for one big file. the plus for moving must have http promises to state resolving is that the actual page change happens only when the client got all the data needed

Comment: Thank you! but if i need it for every state (i have something like 15 different state that look similar)?

Comment: You will need to add "resolve" for every state, but you can use universal service for requests, see @Pankaj Parkar answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell your routes have to be changed like this:

```
.state('category', {
    resolve: {
       data : ($stateParams, dataService) => dataService.getData('path', $stateParams, 'category')
    },
    url: '/category/:type/:id',
    templateUrl : 'templates/pages/category.html',
    controller : 'categoryPage'
})
```

And `getData` method should be refactored to the service (`dataService`)